# Android set dynamic icons

Tags: android, dynamic, notifications, icons

I'm developping a notification App, I want to know if there is a way to dynamically set the Application icon when I recive a new Notification like happen in Whatsapp, with the circled number on the top of the icon,
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature available in android OS itself. The notification badge and dynamic icon like in weather and calendar apps purely depends on the launcher app you are using. For example, Samsung can ship a Samsung calendar app on Samsung devices. Samsung's home screen on those same Samsung devices can have special rules for rendering an icon for Samsung's calendar app, rules that involve showing the day of the month. This is because Samsung wrote the home screen.
Hope you understand the scenario.